# HAProxy not running nodeJS API correctly

Tags: node.js, docker, haproxy, docker-compose

I am running coreOS in EC2.
I have a nodeJS api docker image  and running that in couple of ports (25001 and 25002). When I curl to them, I see proper response.

My intent is to have a HAProxy above these (run at 25000) which will load balance between these two.
So here are steps that I did:

DockerFile for HaProxy:

```
FROM haproxy:1.5
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

haproxy.cfg :

```
global
  # daemon
  maxconn 256
  log /dev/log local0

defaults
  mode http
  log global
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
  bind *:25000
  default_backend node_api

backend node_api
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server api1 localhost:25001
    server api2 localhost:25002
```

Result:
When I run curl for individual services they work --->

```
curl -i localhost:25001/ping
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 68
ETag: W/"44-351401c7"
Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2015 17:22:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
{"error":0,"msg":"loc receiver is alive and ready for data capture"}
```

Same works for 25002
But when I run for 25000, I get a timeout error like below:

```
curl -i localhost:25000/ping
HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
</body></html>
```

I am wondering what am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: How are you starting your Docker containers?

Comment: Docker run -d -p 25000:25000 image name

Comment: That's for the ha one. For node containers - docker run -d -p 2501:2500 --name api1 image

Answer (score 2):

When you tell HAProxy that the back-end server is located at

```
server api1 localhost:25001
```

you're giving an address relative to *the HAProxy container*. But your Node servers aren't running on that container, so there's nobody at localhost.

You've got a few options here.

- You could use the `--link` option for `docker run` to connect HAProxy to your two back-ends.
- You could use the `--net=host` option for `docker run` and then your servers can find each other at localhost
- You could provide HAProxy the address of your host as the back-end address

The first option is the most container-y, but the performance of Docker's bridged network is poor at high loads. The second option is good as long as you don't mind that you're letting everything break out of its container when it comes to the network. The third is kludgey but doesn't have the other two problems.

[Docker's article on networking](http://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) has more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response - quick question - can 2nd option (--net=host) lead to some sort of security hole ?

Comment: Looks like 3rd option is best ... but being new in haproxy struggling how to implement that. Any help would be great !

Comment: Yes, `--net=host` is much less secure because if an attacker gets root on the container then they have root in your host network stack. (They still have to manage the initial break-in, though.)

Comment: A simple method: on your host run `ifconfig` and find your IP address. Put that address into your HAProxy config where you currently have `localhost`. You can find some fancier methods to make it dynamic by using environment variables, but I think that'd work best as a follow-up question.